# How to manage an event in android programming

Tags: java, android

I would like to ask you some information about the managing events in android programming.
In java, when an event occurs, an Event object instance is created and it is passed to the method of the listener class whom implements it; in android I have noticed that all the methods of the listeners class require, as parameter, a View instance, then the first question is the following: when an event occurs, in android, isn't an Event object instance created?
The second doubt I ran into came reading the following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html , here with the attribute android:onClick I can specify the method I want to be executed when an click event occurs, then the problem is the following: why should I speficy a method? Shouldn't I indicate that class whom implements a listener and has inside that particular method that manages that particular event?

Comment: The system you describe in the first sentence is used by Swing, but is certainly not the only way to do it.

Comment: Remember that you can upvote any answers that you found useful in addition to accepting the most helpful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing creates Event objects to send to the methods in its listeners. It is very consistent about following this pattern. Android is not so consistent. It sends [`onClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.view.View%29) a `View`, but it sends [`onKey`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) a `View`, `int`, and `KeyEvent`. This shows that Swing's approach of wrapping everything in an Event object is not the only way to process events.

`android:onClick` is a shortcut to assign a callback method for an onClick event. It assumes will look for that method in the context class of the view which was clicked. Usually this is a subclass of Activity. Certainly, the API designers could have required a class name instead and assumed a certain method name (say, `onClick()`) within that class. However, that not have been much better than using `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: But by code is it possible to assign a method instead a class just as in the shortcut or is it possible only with the shortcut?

Comment: @antox You must send an *object* to `setOnClickListener(). Often this object is created from an anonymous inner class, which essentially accomplishes what you mean by "assign a method".

Answer (score 1):

Android use a system of **callbacks** to manage these sort of events (click, touch, etc.)

For example, when you click on a button `btnMyButton`, the framework will check if there is a [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) attached to it, and if so execute its `onClick()` method.

Listeners methods usually take a `View` argument so you can use the same instance for several `Views`, and adapt the behavior depending on the affected view (usually using `View.getId()` )

the `android:onClick` is just an XML shortcut which can be handy for tiny apps.
For bigger application, I believe it is clearer and less error prone to use [`View.setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) instead.